# Open in an [appName] : Flutter Firebase Plugin

Tags: ios, firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

**Scenario:**

I have a Firebase Dynamic Link implementation using [Firebase Dynamic Link Plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_dynamic_links).

I followed the steps mentioned in the plugin.

**Issue:**

Currently on iOS when user clicks on short / long dynamic link - It asks the dialogue "Open in [appName]".

**Looking for Solution**

Is there a way to prevent the dialogue "open in [appName]" in iOS and just redirect the user with in app pages?

**Info:**

Firebase Dynamic Link [apple-app-site-association](https://researchapp.page.link/apple-app-site-association).

Hosted site [app site association](https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/privateers/apple-app-site-association)

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had was: The browser was sent to a private mode. When I changed the browser setting to a non-private; the dialogue did not appear and seamless redirect happened from browser to an app.